# Android building and debugging a System App

Tags: android

How do you build and debug a system app.  Since I don't have the key to sign the apk with the manufacturer's key while I'm in development, or for every device I'm using, is there a way to use a debug key to sign an app and install it as a system app?

Comment: the eclipse android studio / plugin has a default dev key.  For dev purposes you do not need to sign your apk if you deploy to a simulator - try Genymotion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a rooted device to install an app as a system app and you'll have to remount the system partition as read/write and then copy it over to the system partition. You can find plenty of guides online, for example: http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/

Comment: @Saty If you have a device connected via USB with your system app running, you should be able to debug it from Android Studio just by going to `Run -> Attach Debugger to Android process`, and it should show up (I'm using Android Studio 4.1).

Comment: Addendum to the above comment: do not confuse that menu option with `Attach to process`, also in the Run menu.